# New Thread for Loading animated Gif

Tags: wpf, vb.net, multithreading, backgroundworker

I have read countless pages on how this can be achieved but none seem to be working for me.. I wonder if it is because I am using WPF??

I have an image control on my WPF page that holds an animated gif. Its initial Visibility property is set to hidden - the idea being it will become visible when the user logs in and then disappears once login has been achieved.

So, my first thought was to make the image visible on button click - carry out the grunt work then hide it again. However the image never gets displayed until after all the processing has completed - rendering the idea a useless one.

So, after a bit of digging it seems people have achieved this by processing a new thread and using the Background Worker object. I have tried this but continually get the error:

> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different
>   thread owns it.

My code is as follows:

Global Variable for the thread object:

```
Friend g_thLoading As Thread
```

On button click for login on I have:

```
Private Sub btnLoginOk_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnLoginOk.Click

    g_thLoading = New Thread(AddressOf LoadingImage)
    g_thLoading.IsBackground = True
    g_thLoading.Start()

    Try
        ... Heavy Processing that takes a while ...

    Catch liEX As UnauthorizedAccessException
        txbResults.Text = liEX.Message()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

    g_thLoading.Abort()

End Sub
```

Then the method for making the image visible:

```
Public Sub LoadingImage()

    imgLoading.Visibility = Visibility.Visible

End Sub
```

I have read some posts about the error message stating to Freeze the object (cannot see how this works) and also look at using a Dispatcher - this is a little lost on me though as every example I have tried does not work.

Comment: Have you tried using Dispatcher.Invoke on LoadingImage method? If so, could you please post the code you used?

Comment: No... I have not used Dispatcher.Invoke on that method yet...? How might I go about implementing that on the above code? Thanks Schmaedeck!

Comment: Why are you creating a background thread just to set the visibility of your image? In doing so you have tried to access a UI element on a thread other than the thread it lives on. As schmaedeck said, you need to invoke the call to the UI when required.

Comment: Is there any reason why you are using Threads directly instead of a BackgroundWorker or Tasks (TPL)? As Verdolino pointed out, you are doing your time consuming operation on the GUI thread and run a visibility change async in the background.

Comment: You really should offload your work to another thread leaving your UI thread for doing things with the UI, like your GIF.

Comment: Yeah, I have also looked at Background Wokers and go the same error - so thought Thread may be the most stripped back version and went with that.. Could possibly be wrong there. I also made the initial thought to pass the heavy load over to the new thread - but seems there are other objects in that process that belong to the original thread so was getting the same error again. My thinking was that it may be less work to do to implement the Image visibility through the new thread (rightly or wrongly).